# Would this community benefit from documentation like stack overflow?

Tags: feature-request

As the title says, would we benefit from having documentation?

It's a useful aspect of stack overflow and it's certainly something that I would find useful.

As it stands there is a blender tag on stack overflow that we can create documentation for. But it would be good to have blender documentation reflected or moved here.

Comment: For those interested in helping with the documentation, here is the link for SO https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/blender/commit